# Firebase Nested Search

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a realtime firebase db that resembles the following:

```
/users
    / followers
       /Us23ksjhd8fj
       /0Ujs7hsgdnd
{
  "KmOesOqnHBazLVdfcjk1pAG3HBt1" : {
    "Following" : [ "KmOesOqnHBazLVdfcjk1pAG3HBt1", "zfPwTT64Z5hF6KqMC5zhdOkTqOh1", "xW3K3Iyl9JQ9gxyjqHhJ6JsYu9j2", "xW3K3Iyl9JQ9gxyjqHhJ6JsYu9j2" ]
  },
  "xW3K3Iyl9JQ9gxyjqHhJ6JsYu9j2" : {
    "Following" : [ "KmOesOqnHBazLVdfcjk1pAG3HBt1" ]
  }
}
```

In Firestore I have the normal auth provided info

```
/Users
    / Last_name
    / First_name
    / UID
```

I am looking for a way to parse thu all my Users to give me a hit when one of them is also a follower.  In a way, it is a nested search.  Any ideas of suggestions much apprecaited.

Comment: It's hard to understand your data structure. Can you replace it with the actual JSON from your database (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I updated the realtime db with the JASON.  I can get a list of users from the Firestore but my question how do I cycle thru the followers and and get a hit.  I am ultimatley looking to change a sliders from GREEN to GRAY when a user is also a follower.

Comment: Thanks for that. Now can you also describe what the use-case is in different words, as I'm having a hard time interpreting it? If you have existing, non-working code that would even better./

Comment: Sure.  I have a list of users (stored in Firestore) for my app.  Those attributes are done using the Auth process.  Each user will have a number of followers (think social media type of followers).  I want to be able to list all the users and indicate which of the user list the current user is following,

Comment: If you have the users in Firestore, why are we looking at Realtime Database here?

Comment: I was storing the following in Realtime - maybe best to put it all in one place.  Is there an advantage of Firestore vs realtime?

Comment: The question is unclear. Are you asking how to find a users followers? Or how to load those users? Or something else? Please clarify, indicate your coding platform, include what code you've attempted and update the question and we'll take a look.